# What webpack loader can parse <svg> elements inside html files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-4

I have this kind of element in my soure code which I'm trying to build with webpack:

```
<svg
      version="1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={size}
      height={size}
      viewBox={setView(options)}
      id={id}
    >
      {element}
</svg>
```

However, when I try to build my app, I get this kind of an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/lib/components/element.js 33:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (33:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|   return (
>     <svg
|       version="1"
|       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 @ ./src/lib/index.js 1:0-49 3:15-25
 @ ./src/components/Results.tsx
 @ ./src/components/PageContainer.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
```

I assume this is because I don't have a loader for html files that contain svg tags. I tried installing the svg-loader but it seems to only care about files that end .svg. What module do I need to install in order to build the project with my webpack.config.js? I am using webpack version 4.41.2

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.tsx'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  watch: true,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'),
    port: 2222
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /.tsx?$/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader'] },
      { test: /.html$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
      { test:/\.(s*)css$/, use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      { test: /\.woff(\?.+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?.+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?.+)?$/, use: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?.+)?$/, use: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?.+)?$/, use: 'svg-inline-loader' },
      { test: /\.png$/, use: 'url-loader?mimetype=image/png' },
      { test: /\.gif$/, use: 'url-loader?mimetype=image/gif' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      showErrors: true,
      title: 'React-TS-Webpack App',
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'),
      hash: true
    })
  ]

}
```

Comment: maybe this can help find this on official website webpack  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader/issues/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't about svg tags. I am missing a loader for js-files in my webpack.config. A simple fix is to add a babel-loader like this:

```
 { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
          presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
      } 
}
```